# What's the name of this font?

Tags: riddle, humor

A friend of mine has been tasked with alpha testing a future installment of a popular operating system.

Our friendship was born years ago out of our common passion for typography. No wonder he called me to talk about the new system fonts!

We talked mainly about this weird seriph font that only has the following glyphs:

> ABDEGHJKLNPQUVWXYZ

(Uppercase? Lowercase? We didn't talk about it but I soon realized that it doesn't really matter.)

We were wondering about its possible use when I had a sudden realization and I asked him: "Wait, how is it called?".

Unfortunately, before he could answer me someone waved a non-disclosure agreement under his nose and he had to stop, but I'm pretty sure I got the name right.

I can't wait for the new OS to be released, so I can check if I was right!

---

So, **what's the name of this font?**

---

Now that the correct answer has been found, I'll throw all the hints at you in this spoiler:

- > The missing glyphs are the only letters needed to spell MICROSOFT, which is in fact a popular OS.
- > It is a Serif font. A Serif lacking Microsoft. Serif sans Microsoft.
- > Microsoft Sans Serif is a system font too.
- > I have avoided spelling Serif with its usual spelling, This was both a hint (why am I using seriph instead?) and an attempt to avoid writing a part of the solution myself.

Comment: The answer is obviously CFIMORST because those are the missing letters! That's the real reason he can't talk about it--he literally can't type it out!

Comment: Maybe this is a clue: "Microsoft" uses only the letters CFIMORST.

Comment: That's the joke I was trying to make.... I thought the Microsoft bit was obvious from them missing letters. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It could be something along the lines of

> "Serif sans Microsoft", a reversal of [Microsoft Sans Serif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sans_Serif), since it is a serif font missing the letters of MICROSOFT?

Comment: Along these lines, it could be Comic Sans MS.

Comment: It's a serif font, so that rules out your contribution, I think.

Comment: @NexusInk Read the answer again - my proposal is specifically the first three words.